# Shell Script to Rename an Image File To the Directory Name

Tags: bash, shell

I am having an Image File placed in a Directory:

```
"/root/Desktop/my test dir/image.jpg"
```

I need to rename the Image File as follows (using some shell script):

```
image.jpg => "my test dir.jpg"
```

Note: There is only a Single Image File in this Directory

Can somebody please give me some hint?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you just renaming 1 file or will you be renaming several files?

Comment: @Bryan:I am building an Automated Framework. This needs to be done for SEVERAL Files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dir='/root/Desktop/my test dir/'

dirBase=$(basename -- "$dir") # should be equal to 'my test dir'
file=$(echo "$dir/"*) # things will break if your directory has more than one file
fileExtension=${file##*.} # 'jpg' in your case
mv -- "$file" "$dir/$dirBase.$fileExtension"
```

Comment: How did this even get accepted? ``file="$dir/"*`` wont evaluate correctly. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
mv "/root/Desktop/my test dir/image.jpg" "/root/Desktop/my test dir/my test dir.jpg"
```

Comment: Clever, but not very general.

Comment: No, this is not what I asked for. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

[Parameter substitution.](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)

```
echo "${pathname##*/}"
echo "${pathname%.*}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
x="/root/Desktop/my test dir/image.jpg"

IFS="/" arr=( "$x" )
mv "$x" "${arr[1]}/${arr[2]}/${arr[3]}/${arr[3]}.${arr[4]##*.}"
```